# General Cauchy theorem aplication

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $a \neq b\in \mathbb{C} $ and $U := \mathbb{C} -[a,b] $

Let $\Gamma$ be a cycle in $U$. The following equality is true?

$$\int_{\Gamma} \frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz=0$$

I saw it some notes of a friend. I know it's true for every cycle  $\Gamma$ that is homologous to zero in $U$. But what about the others cycles?

Comment: What do you know about the winding numbers of $\Gamma$ about $a$ and $b$?

Comment: In the notes there is noting about it. But the winding numbers of Γ about a and b maybe there are equal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the comment:

$$\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)} = \frac{1}{a-b}\left(\frac{1}{z-a}-\frac{1}{z-b}\right),$$

hence

$$\int_\Gamma \frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)}\,dz = \frac{1}{a-b}\left(\int_\Gamma\frac{dz}{z-a} - \int_\Gamma \frac{dz}{z-b}\right) = \frac{2\pi i}{a-b} \left(n(\Gamma,a) - n(\Gamma,b)\right).$$

Since $a$ and $b$ belong to the same component of the complement of $U$, we have $n(\Gamma,a) = n(\Gamma,b)$ for every cycle $\Gamma$ in $U$.

Comment: of course partial fraction, thanks alot!